# YA fantasy novel with a girl who finds a forest inside her house or a book

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

In 2009 I read a Young Adult fantasy novel where a girl finds a forest in her home (or a book), and travels through it. It also had a personification of death involved.

I think it was published between 2002-2008, but I can't find anything similar.

Comment: Might it have been [*Inkheart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart)? Published 2003, protagonist is a young girl (Meggie) who finds a whole fantasy world in a book.

Comment: You're not talking about Narnia, are you? (Whole forest inside a wardrobe)

Comment: @Shokhet seems like a possible match, how about kicking that question out of "unanswered" tab now? :)

Comment: You can take the credit for the answer if you want to, @Jenayah. (I don't remember now whether there was a "personification of death" involved in the book or not, and I do not have my copies of the books at hand.)